# Custom AuthenticationHandler not using custom service provider for dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have added a custom authorization scheme like this...

```
public class AuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions>
{
    private readonly IUserIdentifierProvider userIdentifierProvider;

    public AuthHandler(IUserIdentifierProvider userIdentifierProvider, IOptionsMonitor<AuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) :
        base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        this.userIdentifierProvider = userIdentifierProvider;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()    {
        var ticket = ...

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
    public static class AuthMiddlewareAppBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AuthOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            return builder.AddScheme<AuthOptions, AuthHandler>("Custom Scheme", "Custom Auth", configureOptions);
        }
    }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Custom Scheme";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Custom Auth";
            })
            .AddCustomAuth(o => {});

            services.AddDbContext<DomainDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            var serviceProvider = ConfigureUnity(services);

            return serviceProvider;
        }
```

When MVC creates the AuthHandler class upon a request, it doesn't use my dependency injection container returned from ConfigureServices.

I get the exception...

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Web.Auth.Abstract.IUserIdentifierProvider' while attempting to
>   activate 'AuthHandler'.

Why is it not using my container?

It works if I do...

```
services.AddTransient<IUserIdentifierProvider, UserIdentifierProvider>();
```

inside ConfigureServices. It doesn't appear to be looking in my container at all. So where on earth is it getting the instance from? It must be keeping a reference to the IServiceCollection passed to ConfigureServices and uses it instead of the one it's supposed to.

Looking with Reflector, the ConfigureServices method is called by the following function...

```
public static StartupMethods LoadMethods(IServiceProvider hostingServiceProvider, Type startupType, string environmentName)
{
    ConfigureBuilder builder = FindConfigureDelegate(startupType, environmentName);
    ConfigureServicesBuilder builder2 = FindConfigureServicesDelegate(startupType, environmentName);
    ConfigureContainerBuilder configureContainerMethod = FindConfigureContainerDelegate(startupType, environmentName);
    object instance = null;
    if (!builder.MethodInfo.get_IsStatic() || ((builder2 != null) && !builder2.MethodInfo.get_IsStatic()))
    {
        instance = ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(hostingServiceProvider, startupType);
    }
    Func<IServiceCollection, IServiceProvider> configureServicesCallback = builder2.Build(instance);
    Action<object> configureContainerCallback = configureContainerMethod.Build(instance);
    return new StartupMethods(instance, builder.Build(instance), delegate (IServiceCollection services) {
        IServiceProvider provider = configureServicesCallback(services);
        if (provider != null)
        {
            return provider;
        }
        if (configureContainerMethod.MethodInfo != null)
        {
            Type[] typeArray1 = new Type[] { configureContainerMethod.GetContainerType() };
            Type serviceType = typeof(IServiceProviderFactory<>).MakeGenericType(typeArray1);
            object requiredService = hostingServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(serviceType);
            object[] objArray1 = new object[] { services };
            object obj3 = serviceType.GetMethod("CreateBuilder").Invoke(requiredService, objArray1);
            configureContainerCallback(obj3);
            object[] objArray2 = new object[] { obj3 };
            provider = (IServiceProvider) serviceType.GetMethod("CreateServiceProvider").Invoke(requiredService, objArray2);
        }
        else
        {
            provider = hostingServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>>().CreateServiceProvider(services);
        }
        return provider ?? services.BuildServiceProvider();
    });
}
```

If a provider is returned, it's done.

This makes no sense.

Comment: In which class is `IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()` ? Is that your Startup class? It looks part of the Handler.

Comment: That's bad indentation. It's in StartUp. The resolution works fine normally. I suspect AuthenticationBuilder isn't using my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hard coded the dependencies in the auth handler constructor.

Simple, eh?

Comment: I'd love to get some more information on this - would you be able to expand on this please?  Are you successfully resolving dependencies now?

Comment: @JohnReilly No. In fact it happened again with another component. I went through the source code and I couldn't see how this was possible. It seems to be that official MVC components don't always use items registered in a custom container. Maybe if I get time I will create a solution to demonstrate it.